# .render() in Jinja2 does not clash with a function with the same name? Why?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm taking Udacity's web dev course in which the instructor uses this code for his `Handler` class:

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(**params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
```

As you can see, he calls `.render(**params)` in `render_str`. I recently found that `.render()` is a built-in Jinja2 function, so it raises the question: why does the built-in `.render()` not clash with the custom `render():`? How can you name your function the same as a built-in function and not run into problems using them both in the same class?

Comment: This is not a function this is a class method.

Comment: You have self.render() and a t.render(). Two methods with the same name, but part of different objects.

Comment: Ok I get it, if I want to call the third method render() I would preface it with self.render. Otherwise .render defaults to the built-in Jinja method. Thanks guys. That was easy.